# Adding multiple steam desktop shortcuts

Tags: steam

I've just read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52485/how-do-i-add-start-menu-items-to-a-steam-game-after-the-installation) page about creating desktop shortcuts for my games, however steam recently broke for me and I lost all my shortcuts.  Although I can create them one at a time, I have almost 215 games and it would take me at least an hour to sort them.  Is there an easier way to create a mass amount of shortcuts or do I have to do it manually?

If it helps, I use [fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused - you want shortcuts for ALL games, or just for some chosen ones? As far as I know, there's no way to create shortcuts for sets of games natively in Steam, only one by one.

Comment: I would like to create shortcuts for all the games, and it feels so lame that it would take so long, having to go to properties --> general --> create shortcut

Comment: Not that it would make it a lot better, but isn't the "Create Desktop Shortcut" option in the direct context menu of a game, i.e. no need to view the properties? Can't say that with authority though.

Comment: Create Desktop Shortcut is indeed a direct option in the context menu, I assume you cant hold "Shift" or "ctrl" and select all the game you want (I've never tried that on Steam before)

Comment: Alas not WizLiz

Comment: What resolution are you running to try fitting 215 shortcuts on your desktop?

Comment: I'm running 1920*1080.  It's a tight fit but it works.  Also fences stops everything getting messy, they're all in their own group (multiplayer, action, puzzle...).  In reply to WizLiz and No. 7892142, any chance of posting where it is?  I'm either blind or can't see it.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want shortcuts to all of these games. Shortcuts are supposed to make it easier to find things, but if you have your entire desktop covered in icons, you're doing yourself a disservice. What's wrong with the built-in list of games in Steam, the right click menu on the Steam icon, or an app launcher like [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)?

Comment: I find it hard to use the Steam in-built system, as there are no pictures, and that is how I recognize games.  The right click menu on the steam icon shows only the last 10 games played, and I play a wide variety of games often.  Launchy, I have never heard of, and I will check out now!  EDIT - I do not use launchy, because I have no idea what I want to play!  I almost never play the same game twice in two days, and don't have a chance in hell of remembering all of them.  However I have installed launchy because it is very useful for launching files.  Thanks for that!

Comment: @PopeyGilbert " I almost never play the same game twice in two days" You must be the most hardcore casual gamer

Comment: I get bored easily.  Although to be fair I normally gravitate around only 10-15 games, so I tend to play each one at least twice a week.

Comment: @WizLiz Multiselect was just added, but "Create Desktop Shortcut" is not one of the supported actions for a multi-select.  Is having this many desktop shortcuts really that popular?

Comment: Out of an office of 20 people, I believe 5 people have a lot of icons.  I guess it's not that popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a developer, use this: https://gist.github.com/AndrewSav/872b1469e11d9a4b802c

It's a c# script that goes through your installed games and create a shortcut for each. You will need to compile this script either with VS or from command line with csc.exe or run it form LinqPad. All paths are tried to be automatically detected, so if this does not work or not suitable, you need to change the code to hardcode them.

To me this proved to be the fastest and most practical method to achieve what I wanted

Answer (score 10):

I wrote this [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to generate shortcuts (no icon images though)

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Loop, *, 0, 0
{
    if RegExMatch(A_LoopFileName, "appmanifest_\d+\.acf") {
        FileToRead = %A_LoopFileName%
        TempFile := "shortcuts_tempinfo.txt"
        FileDelete, %TempFile%
        RunWait,shortcuts.bat %FileToRead% >> %TempFile%,,Hide
        FileRead,Output,%TempFile%
        FileDelete,%TempFile%
        FoundPos := RegexMatch(Output, """name"".*?""(.*?)""", SubPat)
        Name := RegExReplace(SubPat1, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]")
        StringReplace, LoopFileName, A_LoopFileName, appmanifest_
        StringReplace, LoopFileName, LoopFileName, .acf
        IniWrite, steam://rungameid/%LoopFileName%, %A_Desktop%\%Name%.url, InternetShortcut, URL
    }
}
MsgBox, Finished
```

It needs to be placed inside your SteamApps folder with `shortcuts.bat` (below)

```
@echo off
type %1
```

The script scans through your appmanifest files and creates desktop shortcuts like Steam would, except for the missing icon. (I couldn't figure out a way to find the icon for a game yet due to varying game folder structures)

Comment: That's a very nice program.

Comment: I love to use auto-hotkey, however I've never got to anything as advanced as you have.

Comment: That's really cool, these are actually the `steam://` short-cuts that the steam itself would create, and not just the exe short-cuts. This should be the accepted answer =)

Comment: Neat, though since you're using AHK anyway you might just as well simulate the clicks or key presses that would let Steam create the shortcuts, I guess

Comment: @Zommuter good point, though it would have needed me to switch back to default theme and poke around quite a bit more. I was originally trying to do it in a pure batch script, but I figured autohotkey would be easier soon after starting.

Comment: Just a tiny issue, but the supporting file should be named shortcuts.bat (you indicate it should be just shortcut.bat, note the missing s). The 11th line of the ahk script expects to find a file called shortcuts.bat. Otherwise very very helpful script!

Answer (score 9):

This may not be perfect, as some game folders contain multiple executables, but I've just tested the following on my work system (which only has a few games installed)

- Navigate to your Steam Common Apps folder:

  (commonly C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common)
- Use the Search function in the top right corner and search for ***.exe**
- Select the games from the resulting search you wish to create shortcuts for using **ctrl+left click**
- Right click, and select **send to > desktop**

Not perfect, but it should be faster than manually selecting them!

Comment: Wow!  Thanks so much!  This solution meant it only took 5 minutes.

Comment: If steam is closed, does it start steam before the game ?

Comment: I've just tested this and it does, it acts the same way as regular steam shortcuts and launches the Steam Client Bootstrapper before the application loads.

Comment: One downside is that the file on the desktop is larger.  The normal shortcut is simply a website url something similar to steam://rungameid/230

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I haven't found a way to simply replicate that without having to go through the steam client itself and create them all manually. Hopefully this wouldn't become a major issue though, unless some sort of Desktop redirect is in place.

Comment: This will not work for all games. Terraria is an example of a game that will refuse to launch this way, and needs to be launched through Steam.

Comment: Because this seems to be a problem, and many people might like to have a proper solution, I might program an application to do this.  Shouldn't be hard considering I've worked with the Steam API before.  3ventic beat me to it!

Comment: The advantage of this solution is, for games with more than one exe you can choose which one you want to start. So you can often directly start the game an bypass a launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a solution to this in Python - though you can't choose which are created, it just makes shortcuts for all installed games https://github.com/JeeZeh/steam-shortcut-generator